# How can I log into SourceForge with OpenID?

Tags: openid, sourceforge

When I go to the SourceForge login page at https://sourceforge.net/account/login.php, the OpenID login is no longer displayed.  My account has an OpenID account associated with it with is my normal way of logging in.

What's going on, and how can I log in with OpenID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SourceForge is attempting to phase out OpenID logins in favor of social logins, [according to their support forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/site-support/5782/).

For now, you can append openid to the login page, so it looks like https://sourceforge.net/account/login.php?openid.